# How to divide hours in 15m intervals and distribute the values ​of each hour in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, time, series

```
| Month     | day | hour | Temperature |
|-----------|-----|------|-------------|
| September | 01  | 0:00 | 19,11       |
| September | 01  | 1:00 | 18,67       |
| September | 01  | 2:00 | 18,22       |
| September | 01  | 3:00 | 17,77       |


convert to:

| Month     | day | hour | Temperature |
|-----------|-----|------|-------------|
| September | 01  | 0:00 | T = 19,11       |
| September | 01  | 0:15 | T2 = T + (18,67 - 19,11)/ 4 |
| September | 01  | 0:30 | T3 = T2 + (18,67 - 19,11)/4  |
| September | 01  | 0:45 | T4 = T3 + (18,67 - 19,11)/4 |
| September | 01  | 1:00 | T = 18,67                       |
| September | 01  | 1:15 | T2 = T + (18,22 - 18,67)/ 4 |
| September | 01  | 1:30 | T3 = T2 + (18,22 - 18,67)/4  |
| September | 01  | 1:45 | T4 = T3 + (18,22 - 18,67)/4 |
| September | 01  | 2:00 | T = 18,22       |
```

.
.
.

I have this in an excel file and wanted to make these changes in python. Initially I upload the dataset to a dataframe.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Hint: `.diff` and `cumsum()`

Comment: make 4 duplicate rows for each hour, and then add a ranking column for each hour.

Comment: i have some difficulties in programming in python. could you give me a little example to see if i understood?

Comment: My suggestion: Create a column of pandas timeseries (using `pd.to_dateime`), create new rows for the empty 15 minutes intervals, and than [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) 'Temperature' column. I think you can use `interpolate` to create the new rows.

Comment: I am not able to understand very well. The temperature calculation should be as shown in the question. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Isn't your calculation just linear [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) of data? (creating new datapoints based on original data)

Comment: @MárioPires: lets work on it tommorow. I am stuck at the syntax so unable to help you right now.

Comment: Does my answer help? or you are still stuck? If it helps then don't forget to upvote and close the question by accepting it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a sample code:

```
x = df.Temperature.str.split(",", expand=True)
```

---

**x:**

```
    0   1
0   19  11
1   18  67
2   18  22
3   17  77
```

---

```
y = x[0].astype(int).diff().div(4).fillna(x.iloc[0,0]).astype(float).cumsum()
```

**y:**

```
0    19.00
1    18.75
2    18.75
3    18.50
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Do it for other column as well and then merge them together to get `"<num1>, <num2>"`

### 1st stage: resample:

```
df[['temp1', 'temp2']] = df.Temperature.str.split(",", expand=True)
df['temp1'] = df['temp1'].astype(int)
df['temp2'] = df['temp2'].astype(int)

u = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='%H:%M')#.dt.hour
df['hr'] = u.dt.hour
df = df.set_index(u)
df1 = df.resample('900s').pad()
```

---

**df1:**

[image]

### 2nd Stage

`<to be continued>`

## Edit2:

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='%H:%M')
df.set_index('hour', inplace=True)
v = df.resample('15T').bfill().reset_index()

v[['temp1', 'temp2']] = v.Temperature.str.split(",", expand=True)
v['temp1'] = v['temp1'].astype(int)
v['temp2'] = v['temp2'].astype(int)

t = v.groupby(v['hour'].dt.hour)
    
def calc(val1, val2):
    diff1 = (val1['temp1']-val2['temp1'])
    diff1.iloc[0]= val1['temp1'].iloc[0]*4
    
    diff2 = (val1['temp2']-val2['temp2'])
    diff2.iloc[0]= val1['temp2'].iloc[0]*4
    
    t1_group = diff1.div(4).cumsum()
    t2_group = diff2.div(4).cumsum()
    
    return list(zip(t1_group, t2_group))

concat_res = []
for _, gr in t:
     concat_res.append(calc(gr, gr.iloc[0]))

flatten = lambda t: [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
v['Temperature'] = flatten(concat_res)
v = v.drop(['temp1', 'temp2'],axis=1)
```

---

**v:**

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand the reason for separating the temperature.
my idea is to do a 'for' cycle and go through the dataframe that has the temperature. then another 'for' cycle to write 4 in 4 on the dataframe with the date every 15m

Comment: The idea of separating them is to make calculation easy on them. You can do this without that also by using apply. I will update my answer.

Comment: @MárioPires: I have updated my answer. The issue is if you don't split them it will add un-necessary complexity to it. That's why better to split and then combine them using zip.

Answer (score 0):

There are `pandas` builtin tools for doing this; the main hurdle is converting the data to a more friendly format.  Here is the "worst-case", where the timestamp is separated over columns, the temperatures use a comma as a decimal, and everything is a string:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': 'September',
                   'day': '01',
                   'hour': ['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00'],
                   'temperature': ['19,11', '18,67', '18,22', '17,77']})

#        month day  hour temperature
# 0  September  01  0:00       19,11
# 1  September  01  1:00       18,67
# 2  September  01  2:00       18,22
# 3  September  01  3:00       17,77
```

Here's how you can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the time information to datetime objects:

```
dates = df['hour'] + ', ' + df['month'] + ' ' + df['day'] + ', ' + '2020'
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)
```

And here's how you can convert the temperatures into floats:

```
temps = df['temperature'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

You can then make a new DataFrame which just the dates and the temperatures, `resample` and `interpolate` to get the imputed temperatures:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'temperature': temps.values},
                  index=dates)
result = df.resample('15T').interpolate()
```

Result:

```
                     temperature
2020-09-01 00:00:00      19.1100
2020-09-01 00:15:00      19.0000
2020-09-01 00:30:00      18.8900
2020-09-01 00:45:00      18.7800
2020-09-01 01:00:00      18.6700
2020-09-01 01:15:00      18.5575
2020-09-01 01:30:00      18.4450
2020-09-01 01:45:00      18.3325
2020-09-01 02:00:00      18.2200
2020-09-01 02:15:00      18.1075
2020-09-01 02:30:00      17.9950
2020-09-01 02:45:00      17.8825
2020-09-01 03:00:00      17.7700
```

---

If you want to get the time information back to separate columns, you could do something like this:

```
formatted = result.index.strftime('%B,%d,%H:%M').str.split(',').to_list()
result[['month', 'day','hour']] = formatted
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`result` is now:

```
    temperature      month day   hour
0       19.1100  September  01  00:00
1       19.0000  September  01  00:15
2       18.8900  September  01  00:30
3       18.7800  September  01  00:45
4       18.6700  September  01  01:00
5       18.5575  September  01  01:15
6       18.4450  September  01  01:30
7       18.3325  September  01  01:45
8       18.2200  September  01  02:00
9       18.1075  September  01  02:15
10      17.9950  September  01  02:30
11      17.8825  September  01  02:45
12      17.7700  September  01  03:00
```